Copying text in a div
I have a JavaScript code that generates styled text:
function applyStyle() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  var selectedStyle = document.getElementById('styleSelect').value;
  var styledText = document.getElementById('styledText');
  var styleMap = {
    'light-text-bubbles': {
      'a': 'ⓐ', 'b': 'ⓑ', 'c': 'ⓒ', 'd': 'ⓓ', 'e': 'ⓔ', 'f': 'ⓕ', 'g': 'ⓖ', 'h': 'ⓗ', 'i': 'ⓘ', 'j': 'ⓙ', 'k': 'ⓚ', 'l': 'ⓛ', 'm': 'ⓜ', 'n': 'ⓝ', 'o': 'ⓞ', 'p': 'ⓟ', 'q': 'ⓠ', 'r': 'ⓡ', 's': 'ⓢ', 't': 'ⓣ', 'u': 'ⓤ', 'v': 'ⓥ', 'w': 'ⓦ', 'x': 'ⓧ', 'y': 'ⓨ', 'z': 'ⓩ'
    },
  };
  var decoratedText = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
    decoratedText += styleMap[selectedStyle][inputText[i].toLowerCase()] || inputText[i];
  }
  styledText.textContent = decoratedText;
}

and the text appears in this div:
<div id="styledText"></div>

Now I want to create a copy text button.
I tried putting this button to the HTML:
<button onclick="CopyText()">Copy text</button>

and then adding this function to my JavaScript:
function CopyText() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("styledText");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}

but it didn't work

Does this answer your question? How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Div elements do not have the select() method it can only be used on textarea or input elements.
To Copy text from 'div' you can use the navigator.clipboard.writeText() method by passing the text of the div.
Here is how you can use it
function CopyText() {
  var textToCopy = document.getElementById("styledText").textContent;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy).then(function() {
    console.log('Text copied successfully');
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('Could not copy text: ', err);
  });
}

This copies the txt content of styledText div to clipboard.
